# Entropy solution to scalar conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

The entropy solution of the scalar conservation law

$$u_t + f(u)_x =0 \\ u(0,x)=u_0(x) $$

is defined as a function $u(t,x) \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies for any $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R} ; \mathbb{R}^+)$ and $ k \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}} |u-k|\phi_t + \hbox{sgn}(u-k)(f(u)-f(k))\phi_x dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_0(x)\phi(0,x) dx \geq 0$$

In Denis Serre, "Systems of Conservation Laws 1" page 34, it is claimed that in order to ensure uniqueness of the entropy solutions it is necessary to enforce the integral inequality above to test functions which might be non zero in ${0} \times \mathbb{R}$, meaning that one would check reduce the validity of the above integral inequality to test function with support in $\mathbb{R}_{*}^+\times\mathbb{R}$ there could be an example of initial data for which there exists two entropy solutions.
Anyone could point me to such an example !

Comment: Otherwise the constant $u=k$ is a solution. Basically you need the test function to "see" the initial condition.

Comment: No I don't think that was what he was meaning, you could still get the initial data by adding a condition along the line $u \in C^0(L^1_{loc})$ and  $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$ a.e.

I believe he says that if don't enforce the integral inequality until the time t=0 then you might loose uniqueness

Comment: Writing $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$ does not force the boundary conditions to be attained continuously in any sense. You can set $u=k$ for $t>0$ and $u=u_0$ for $t=0$.

Comment: Yes but then u wouldn't be in $C^0(L^1_{loc})$ because it wouldn't be continuous at time t=0

Comment: I suggest you reformulate the question then; this is not what you asked originally (and it's not clear this is what Serre is getting at either).